# Reinforcement Learning Policy Gradient two different update method with reward?

Tags: keras, reinforcement-learning

I was looking at 2 different examples for policy gradient, and was wondering why there are 2 different methods for getting the advantage function.
One of them at https://github.com/flyyufelix/VizDoom-Keras-RL/blob/master/reinforce.py which sets the advantage straight to the discounted reward

```
advantages[i][self.actions[i]] = discounted_rewards[i]
```

and passes this straight to categorical cross entropy.

The other one at https://github.com/MorvanZhou/Reinforcement-learning-with-tensorflow/blob/master/contents/7_Policy_gradient_softmax/RL_brain.py which has

```
loss = tf.reduce_mean(neg_log_prob * self.tf_vt)
```

which he then tries to minimize (tf_vt is just discounted_reward, calculated in the same way as the one above).

Shouldn't the first one method be

```
advantages[i][self.actions[i]] = probability_from_softmax * discounted_rewards[i]
```

if they were to be the same?  Or am I misunderstanding the difference between manually calculating negative log probabilities here?

Comment: There are now good tutorials from Tensorflow that do A2C training and Eval in a controlled and reliable fashion using TF agents

Answer (score 1):

I think its one and the same. They are just writing in two different ways. The first definition calculates the advantage function while the second one calculates the loss directly. Advantage function just gives how much this particular reward is advantageous as compared to the average reward (value). If you provide the value as zero, you get the first definition. Now, the loss needs to be calculated. So the categorical cross entropy gives the log probabilities multiplied by advantage. In the second definition, this entire thing is done manually.

Comment: So compared to DQN, where loss is (TD target-Prediction)^2, what is the loss of REINFORCE?  The original algorithm is θ ← θ + α∇θ logπθ(st,at)vt 
Secondly, since it's only setting the action that's being taken with the reward, would the others be affected by it during cross entropy?  e.g. why isn't the advantages[i][self.actions[i]] = softmax[i] being set, kind of like how they are for DQN algorithms?

Comment: I would compare REINFORCE to the supervised learning algorithms. Loss is action probabilities multiplied by rewards which is similar to supervised loss (weighted by rewards). In case of your second question, the loss is updating the policy network. So all the policy network needs to know is for the given state, what is the best action to be taken. I understand that you are confusing it with DQN but in this case, you are directly going from states to actions without updating Q-values.